# makefile with .s files beside .c files

Tags: linux, makefile

I have a baremetal project which includes .s files beside .c files. How can I write a makefile where I separate the compilation of the .s files from the .c files? The files are located in subfolders (source, include, startup) of a program.

I was going for something like this. Is this good? How can I link the objects into an executable then?

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
ROOT := $(shell pwd)
VPATH := $(ROOT)/source:/$(ROOT)/startup:$(ROOT)/include
EXE := exe
OBJECTS_GCC := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))
OBJECTS_AS := $(patsubst %.s,%.o,$(wildcard *.s))
AS := arm-none-eabi-as -mcpu=arm926ej-s -Wall
GCC := arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=arm926ej-s -Wall
LD := arm-none-eabi-ld -T test.ld -o $(EXE)

all: $(EXE)
$(EXE): startups sources

startups: $(OBJECTS_AS)
    $(AS) $(OBJECTS_AS)

sources: $(OBJECTS_GCC)
    $(GCC) $(OBJECTS_GCC)
```

I am having a hard time finding any example at all which includes .s files alongside .c files.

Regards.

---

Here is the latest version of makefile, where header.h isn't found:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
ROOT := $(shell pwd)
INC := $(ROOT)/inc
SRC := $(ROOT)/src
STR := $(ROOT)/str
EXE := exe
AS := arm-none-eabi-as -mcpu=arm926ej-s -c -Wall -I $(INC) -I$(SRC) -I $(STR)
GCC := arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=arm926ej-s -c -Wall -I $(INC) -I$(SRC) -I $(STR)
LDSCRIPT := test.ld
LD := arm-none-eabi-ld -T $(LDSCRIPT)
HEADERS := $(notdir $(wildcard $(INC)/*.h))
SOURCES_GCC := $(notdir $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.c))
SOURCES_AS := $(notdir $(wildcard $(STR)/*.s))
OBJECTS_GCC := $(SOURCES_GCC:.c=.o)
OBJECTS_AS := $(SOURCES_AS:.s=.o)
VPATH := $(STR):$(SRC):$(INC)

all : $(EXE)
    @echo konec postopka: izvrsljiv program po imenu $(EXE) se nahaja v mapi $(ROOT)

$(EXE) : $(OBJECTS_AS) $(OBJECTS_GCC)
    @echo objekti so: $(OBJECTS_AS) $(OBJECTS_GCC)
    @echo headerji so: $(HEADERS)
    @echo linkanje objektov v izvrsljiv program...
    $(LD) -o $@ $^

%.o : %.s %.h
    @echo prevajanje ASSEMBLY izvornih datotek...
    $(AS) -o $@  $<

%.o : %.c %.h
    @echo prevajanje C izvornih datotek...
    $(GCC) -o $@ $<

.PHONY : clean
clean :
    @echo brisanje objektov
    rm *.o
    @echo brisanje izvrsljivega programa
    rm $(EXE)
```

Comment: In response to the updated makefile, I have no idea why header.h is not found, if it indeed exists in the directory inc. I do note however, that you stated in one of your comments that header.h is your only header, but the implicit rule you defined looks for a separate header for each object file. If there only is one header file, and each object file depends on it, you should explicitly mention it, instead of using the pattern %.h. Change your pattern rule to `%.o : %.s header.h`, or remove %.h from the pattern rule, and put in the following line: `$(OBJECTS_AS) $(OBJECTS_GCC) : header.h`.

Comment: Maybe you should start a new question for this new issue of the missing header. Include your latest makefile and the exact error message you receive when running it.

Comment: I did start new topic and we managed to solve some problems. The makefile seems to work now. This makefile is ment for another project that has same tree structure and a lot more headers in inc folder, soo changing %.h to header.h is not an option. Please take a look in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626606/make-uses-cc-instead-of-arm-none-eabi-as

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about what commands you would issue without `make`. What steps would you take? Which files do you create first, and how do files depend on the existence of others before they can be made?
Once you have a clear picture of that, write make rules that mimic those commands, but with the inclusion of make variables.

If you have that down, you can then enhance your makefile by using things like implicit rules, automatic variables, and such, but keep it simple at first, until you get a grasp of how `make` works.

A couple of points:

- I don't think the wildcard function will pick up any file names in this way. It only looks in the current directory, and doesn't use VPATH to search in others.
- You use gcc with the objects as inputs. This way it will (try to) create an executable.
- You have no rules to create the object files. This may be fine if you rely on `make`'s built-in implicit or pattern rules, but it won't use the version of gcc you want to use, with it's associated flags. You have to set up some other variables for that to work (like `CC`, `CFLAGS`, and such).
- You have defined `LD`, but never use it. Use it in a recipe to create the executable.

I guess you should have something more like this:

```
all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJECTS_AS) $(OBJECTS_GCC)
    $(LD) $^

%.o: %.s
    $(AS) $<

%.o: %.c
    $(GCC) -c $<
```

Comment: Does this part of code loop until all .s files are read?  %.o: %.s
    $(AS) $<

Comment: @71GA: It provides a general pattern for creating a *.o file from the corresponding *.s file. The line `$(EXE): $(OBJECTS_AS) $(OBJECTS_GCC)` informs make that all those object files are required before attempting to create $(EXE). For each object file separately `make` then looks if it can find a rule to build it. If a *.s file exists which has the same name (without extension) as a *.o file it executes the command following `%.o: %.s`. If it can't find such a *.s file, it sees if it can find a *.c file which matches the *.o file and then executes the command after `%.o: %.c`.

Comment: One more thing. If i use $(OBJECTS_AS) $(OBJECTS_GCC) as prerequisites for target $(EXE) i get unresolved references, BUT if i put actual names of my files (that are startup.o & test.c) as prerequisites my make file works. There must be one more mistake.

Comment: @71GA: Are you sure those two variables aren't empty? As I mentioned, I don't think the wildcard function will pick up files from other directories. Try to echo their value to check. Add a command like `@echo OBJECTS_AS: $(OBJECTS_AS)` to the rule for building $(EXE).

Comment: True these two variables are empty. Which make function/option enables me to pick files from other folders than root folder?

Comment: Thank you for your help eriktous. BUt i have 1 more problem when i try to include headers... If i define prerequisites like this: %.o : %.c %.h i get an error saying that header.h which is my only header and is located in subfolder ./inc cannot be found. This is weird as i did include ./inc path in variable VPATH and i allso included it in a compiler command using -I option.

Comment: That's weird indeed. Could you edit your original question and add your latest makefile at the end?

Comment: Well it looks like makefile was written ok. The reason why it reported errors is, because .s exttension in Eclipse IDE isnt recognized as assembly file. I had to rename it in .S and fix the makefile accordingly. Regards Ziga.